# Android. How to Do Audio Recording with High Volume?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I will describe briefly my trouble with audio recording.

So, I am doing audio recording using MediaRecorder, but unfortunately when I playback the recorded audio, I have media with a very low volume. I hardly hear anything.

Is there any possibility to setup recording volume?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this while recording - but while playing, you can use the [`setVolume(float, float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)) method on `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue on the Nexus One while using Froyo when the AudioManager was set to MODE_IN_CALL.  Try setting it to MODE_NORMAL.  This fixed the problem for me.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```